# Let $X$ a normal random variable with mean 1 and variance 4.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ a normal random variable with mean 1 and variance 4.

a) Find $P(|X|\leq 1)$

**My work**

Note $P(|X|\leq 1)=P(-1\leq X \leq 1)$
Let $Z=\frac{X-1}{2}$ then

$P(|X|\leq 1)=P(\frac{-2}{2}\leq \frac{X-1}{2}<0)=P(-1\leq Z\leq0)=0,3413.$

b) Find the probability function of $X$

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then the pdf $f$ is given by
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\quad (x\in\mathbb{R}).
$$